# Warning: file_get_contents failed to open stream: No such file or directory?

Tags: php, ssh, upload, scp

Here in this Iam uploading a file and then trying to send this file to another VM.

**Code here**

```
// Debugging information -- No use in output    
echo "</p>";
echo '<pre>';
echo 'Here is some more debugging info:';
print_r($_FILES);
print "</pre>";
$file_name = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
echo $file_name;
echo gettype($file_name);
echo "<br/>";
```

**Output:**

```
Here is some more debugging info:Array
(
    [userfile] => Array
        (
            [name] => 6274e8cb0358ef3e3906a91036bc84138a8fde606a6e926b9a580c79f9cfc489
            [type] => application/octet-stream
            [tmp_name] => /tmp/php3Yt3T5
            [error] => 0
            [size] => 3107800
        )

)
6274e8cb0358ef3e3906a91036bc84138a8fde606a6e926b9a580c79f9cfc489string
```

And it is printing the details correctly.But when i try to send this file to remote VM,it is creating errors.

Code continuation

```
$localFile='/var/www/uploads/$file_name';
echo $localFile;
$remoteFile='/home/nsadmin/$file_name';
$host='192.168.150.85';
$port=22;
$user='someusername';
$pass='somepassword';

$connection= ssh2_connect($host,$port);
ssh2_auth_password($connection, $user, $pass);
$sftp = ssh2_sftp($connection);

$stream = fopen("ssh2.sftp://$sftp$remoteFile", 'w');
$file = file_get_contents($localFile);
fwrite($stream, $file);
fclose($stream);
```

**Error Log:**

```
 /var/www/uploads/$file_name Warning: file_get_contents(/var/www/uploads/$file_name): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/MTP/upload.php on line 111
```

Any suggestions on how to fix this error.

P.S :

I have used these for debugging at the start of php file

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors',1);
ini_set('log_errors',1);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try string like this it may help

Just use . for concatenating.

```
$localFile='/var/www/uploads/$file_name';
```

to

```
$localFile='/var/www/uploads/'.$file_name;
```

and

```
$remoteFile='/home/nsadmin/$file_name';
```

to

```
 $remoteFile='/home/nsadmin/'.$file_name;
```

Answer (score 4):

in php you can't use variable in single quotes use double quotes or use variables outside the string

```
$localFile='/var/www/uploads/$file_name';
```

change it to

```
$localFile='/var/www/uploads/'.$file_name; or $localFile="/var/www/uploads/$file_name";
```

Answer (score 2):

change

```
   $localFile='/var/www/uploads/$file_name';
```

to

```
   $localFile="/var/www/uploads/$file_name";
```

$variables are not parsed inside ' quotes

Another way just

```
   $localFile="/var/www/uploads/".$file_name;
```

Same with remote.